# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges with Oracle view using Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Environment

1. Oracle 11g
2. EntityFramework 6.1.1
3. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v 12.1.022
4. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v 12.1.022

I am getting `ORA-01031` error when executing LINQ statement in MVC application controller using Entity Framework.

The LINQ statement is being executed against Oracle view with user that is not an Oracle schema owner. All grants are being set through Oracle role.

Here is Oracle definition

```
--ROLE 

DROP ROLE DART_PORTAL; 

CREATE ROLE DART_PORTAL NOT IDENTIFIED; 

-- Object privileges granted to DART_PORTAL 
GRANT SELECT ON GISPROD.B$FIM_D_POLE_VISINSP_N TO DART_PORTAL; --table 
GRANT SELECT ON GISPROD.FIM_D_POLE_VISINSP_N TO DART_PORTAL; --view 
GRANT EXECUTE ON GISPROD.LTT_USER TO DART_PORTAL; --package is being utilized in VIEW  

-- Grantees of DART_PORTAL
GRANT DART_PORTAL TO DART WITH ADMIN OPTION;        --user 
GRANT DART_PORTAL TO GISPROD WITH ADMIN OPTION;     --schema owner 

--USER 

DROP USER DART CASCADE; 

CREATE USER DART 
  IDENTIFIED BY <password> 
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE GISDEV 
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP 
  PROFILE DEFAULT 
  ACCOUNT UNLOCK; 
  -- 3 Roles for DART 
  GRANT DART_INTERFACE TO DART WITH ADMIN OPTION; --another role 
  GRANT DART_PORTAL TO DART WITH ADMIN OPTION; --role from the role script 
  GRANT RESOURCE TO DART; 
  ALTER USER DART DEFAULT ROLE ALL; 
  -- 5 System Privileges for DART 
  GRANT ALTER SESSION TO DART; 
  GRANT CREATE SESSION TO DART; 
  GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO DART; 
  GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO DART; 
  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO DART;
```

1. When I use the user DART to login using Toad software I can execute select statement against table and view.
2. When I use the same user on Server Explorer in Visual Studio  - tables and view nodes are empty.
3. I can query Oracle table using LINQ but not Oracle View.
4. Using view is important, because each `B$` table in our GIS system has transactional records such `ADD`, `DELETE`, `EDIT`.

   This is transactional representation is built-in by vendor. Each view eliminates these transactional records.

Can you tell me what Oracle permissions I am missing ?

And, can I use Oracle view with Entity Framework ?

If not, I guess I have to build custom LINQ extension method to eliminate those transactional records when selecting records directly from Oracle table.

Connection string defined in `web.config`:

```
<add name="GisStageDbContext" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=SERVERNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME;USER ID=DART;PASSWORD=PASSWORD" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

I created simple controller action and returned user to MVC view

This code works:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{

var test = _testContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select user from dual").First();

ViewBag.User = test;

return View();

}
```

I am still getting the same error when querying the Oracle view but not the Oracle table

This code works as expected with table name

```
[Table(name:"B$FIM_D_POLE_VISINSP_N")]
public partial class FimPole
{

    [Key]
    [Column(name: "G3E_ID", Order = 0)]
    [Display(Name = "G3E ID")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "FIM_STATE")]
    [Display(Name = "Fim State")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 15)]
    public string FimState { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "INSPECTION_STATUS")]
    [Display(Name = "inspection Status")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 15)]
    public string InspectionStatus { get; set; }

}
```

This code does not work and give me the error

```
[Table(name:"FIM_D_POLE_VISINSP_N")]
public partial class FimPole
{
//Same fields
}
```

Database context class is

```
public class VisualInspectionDbContext : DbContext
{

  public VisualInspectionDbContext()
    : base("name=GisStageDbContext"){}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("GISPROD");

  }
  public DbSet<AssetPole> AssetPoles { get; set; }
  public DbSet<FimPole> FimPoles { get; set; }
}
```

I have to talk to our Oracle DBA and ask his opinion.

Thank you.

Comment: LINQ and EF have nothing to do with your error.  Clearly EF is not connecting to the database using the `DART` user.  Have you checked your connection string?

Comment: I just mentioned LINQ because I am using it in my MVC project. Connection string is 100% right. If I change my view to table name - the query works. [Table("TableName")] MyClass{ } works. [Table("ViewName")] MyClass{ } DOES NOT WORK. The same connection string that is defined in web.config

Comment: Let's put it to the test. Can you run this, and tell us what string comes back? `context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select user from dual").First();`

Comment: If I use schema owner in connection string and decorate C# class this way - [Table("ViewName")] MyClass{ } - I am getting another error: object name is already in use. I have all details at work and can provide them tomorrow. I really appreciate your help. I will run the test tomorrow.

Comment: If you have more details tomorrow, make sure to add them to your post by editing it. Better to do that than to keep adding comments.  More people will see the new information that way.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: So when you did `var test = _testContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select user from dual").First();`, what value was returned in `var test`?

Comment: And one more thing, can you post the full error + stack trace that you are getting?

Comment: I resolve the problem. I will edit my post in a moment. Thank you for your time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do NOT write the solution in the question. Copy your answer among the other answers and select it as the proper one.

Comment: I did. thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 5):

This has been resolved. Because I am working with existing Oracle database, I had to disable database initializer.

```
        public VisualInspectionDbContext()
    : base("name=GisStageDbContext")
{

    Database.SetInitializer<VisualInspectionDbContext>(null);

}
```

Basically DART user is low privilege user and does not have any permissions to create database table. Each time DBContext object initializes - Entity Framework was trying to create Oracle table under user that does not have permissions. Anyway if you work with existing database - disable initializer, otherwise; each table will be recreated based on C# class definition.
 I hope this post will help other people.

Regards,

Serghei